# Changing values of a particular key in map

Tags: c++, stl

I have a map

```
std::map<int,int> Table;

Table.insert(pair<int, int>(5, 1)); 
Table.insert(pair<int, int>(4, 2)); 
Table.insert(pair<int, int>(3, 3)); 
Table.insert(pair<int, int>(2, 4));
```

I want to know how to change the value for a particular key. 
For eg. For key 4, I want to increment the value to 3

Comment: `Table[4] = 3;`?

Comment: You have to iterate over your keys, find the one and change its value. However, if this is your only use case, i recommend using an unordered_map

Comment: @AliKanat There is absolutely no reason to iterate, when you know the key.

Comment: Increment would be `++Table[4];`

Comment: @churill ah thanks for the clarification. What is the complexity here then? and also if you compare it to an unordered_map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is your best friend in such cases.

You should use [`operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) from `std::map`. It returns a reference to the value that is mapped to the given key.
Note that if the given key does not already exist in the map, it will be inserted.

Your example (key: 4, increment by 1/set the value to 3) would be:

```
++Table[4];
```

Or directly:

```
Table[4] = 3;
```

---

Since [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), you have the [at()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) member from `std::map` that performs the same as `operator[]()` except that it will not try to insert the key if it does not exist but will throw an [`std::out_of_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) exception instead.

Answer (score 1):

you can use operator[ ] to insert new key or change value of old key like:

> Note: If k does not match the key of any element in the container, the
>   function inserts a new element with that key

```
std::map<int, int> Table;

Table[5] = 1;
Table[4] = 2;
Table[3] = 3;
Table[5] = 4;
```

also, you can use at() funnction for change value of key but with this function can't insert a new key like:

```
std::map<int, int> Table;

Table[5] = 1;
Table.at(5) = 10; // Note that Table.at(3) throws an exception when it does not exist.
```

If you only want to search the container for and element with a key equivalent to k and did not add a new key, I suggest using it:

```
std::map<int, int> table;

int k = 4; 

Table[5] = 1;
Table[4] = 2;
Table[3] = 3;

if (Table.find(k) != Table.end())
  Table.at(k)++; //or Table[k]++;
```